# Cannot contact my realm for credentials

Tags: kerberos

I have created a KERBEROS.TEST realm on my Ubuntu 14.10 virtual machine and after `addprinc root/admin` also I added my client machine as principal.

I checked `kinit` and with `sudo klist` command I received the ticket on my kerberos server, but from my client machine, I receive this message: `Cannot contact any realm 'KERBEROS.TEST' while getting initial credentials`

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry this was caught so late, but this should have been asked on ServerFault or SuperUser.

Answer (score 2):

> "Cannot contact any realm 'KERBEROS.TEST' while getting initial credentials"

Your client needs to contact a KDC for the `KERBEROS.TEST` relam.  It was either unable to find a KDC, or unable to contact a KDC.

To find what you're doing wrong, you'll need to investigate and eliminate various scenarios.

1. Do you have a config file (`/etc/krb5.conf`) that names the realm?
2. Can your client find the domain name of the KDC ?

   - The client could find KDCs in the `[realms]` section of the `krb5.conf`
   - The client could find KDCs through DNS using SRV records.
3. Can the client connect to the KDC ?

If your client knows the realm, the problem is probably in step #2 or step #3.

If you are using MIT Kerberos, here are links to documentation that may help:

- [Realm configuration decisions](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-latest/doc/admin/realm_config.html) including naming and finding KDCs.
- [MIT Kerberos clients support a KRB5_TRACE variable](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-latest/doc/admin/env_variables.html) which could let you get more details about the internal details:

  - `KRB5_TRACE=/tmp/tracefile.txt kinit`, and then inspect the tracefile.